# Entire functions described by two conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

I'm currently reviewing for a qualifying exam and I was looking at old exams, and the following question had stumped me for a couple of days now, and I wanted to see if anyone had a hint; it's for a complex analysis qual. The Statement:

Find all entire functions $f$ such that $f(z+i) = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(z+1) = e^{2 \pi} f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

A hint would be really appreciated; I don't want a full solution since I'm really trying to figure this out, and it just doesn't seem like it be a good studying habit to have the solution given to me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the hands on approach of writing $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$, where $u,v:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations and the question statements?

Comment: no, I hadn't thought of using the C-R equations; I was trying to play around with the Taylor expansion, since the functions are entire. I'll see what I can do with the C-R equations!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $e^{-2\pi z}f(z)$ is doubly periodic.

Comment: Good hint! ${}{}$

Comment: If OP has seen elliptic functions this is pretty easy now; if not, then consider the behavior of this function on and inside the square with vertices $\{0, 1, i, 1+i\}$

Comment: I have not seen elliptic functions, so I will try your hint and the hint with the C-R equations and see if I can get anything from them!

Comment: When you say "this function" you mean  "e^{-2\pi z}f (z) $, or the original function $f$? @MCT

Comment: @m2271r The function $e^{- 2 \pi i z} f(z)$. In general, consider complex functions which are doubly periodic, say  satisfying $f(z + \omega_1) = f(z), f(z + \omega_2) = f(z)$, where $\omega_1, \omega_2$ are not real multiples of each other. If $f$ is also holomorphic, then it is holomorphic on the compact parallelogram formed by $\{0, \omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_1 + \omega_2\}$. Try to deduce that $f$ must be a constant.